# How can I perform math when jquery class equals a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to manipulate an amount based on the name of class that changes with jQuery.  My amount comes from here:

```
<script>
var inboundAmount = <?php echo json_encode($inbound); ?>;
</script>
```

Let's just say that amount is 10.

I output with a bit of php and script like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"#inbound\" class=\"$inbound_status first$id\" onclick=\"comtype($id,'inbound', $vendor)\">$<script>document.write(inboundAmount);</script></a>";
```

The class changes when a user clicks on it.  Sample classes are as follows:

```
half first3547
pending first3547
paid first3547
```

What I've been trying to do is make it so that if the class contains the word 'half', then it would do some math:

```
document.write(inboundAmount/2);
```

Producing the number 5.
I've tried this and some variations with no luck:

```
if ($("#mycontent").find("a.half").length > 0) {document.write(inboundAmount/2);}
```

'mycontent' is the id for the table that a href exists in.

I have also tried the following:

```
if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'half' ) ) { {document.write(inboundAmount/2);}
```

still to no avail.

A full example is this:

```
<td class='grav-results-td'>
<?php if (!empty($check_inbound)):echo "<a href=\"#inbound\" 
class=\"$inbound_status first$id\" onclick=\"comtype($id,'inbound', 
$vendor)\">$<script>if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'half' ) ) 
{document.write(inboundAmount/2);}</script></a>"; endif; ?></td>
```

And I have also tried the manipulation in the success area of my ajax script.

**Answering some of the questions below:**

$inbound_status first$id is a PHP variable.

The output of document.write(inboundAmount/2); is working correctly and showing half the amount of document.write(inboundAmount);

Comment: Where exactly do you put the `if ($("#mycontent").find("a.half").length > 0) {document.write(inboundAmount/2);}` code? In a `setInterval` event? `onClick` event? Somethign else?

Comment: @user202729 I updated the question with a full example of the code.  It is at the bottom of the question.  It is wrapped in a <td>

Comment: @user202729 sorry.  It's updated.

Comment: Can you try replacing `document.write(inboundAmount/2);` with `document.write(inboundAmount);` to see what outputs? I've a feeling that the javascript side isnt reading the variable `inboundAmount` at all

Comment: Is there any output in the first place?

Comment: @samleo It outputs correctly, if I take out the conditional.  So I think the conditional is the part that is messing it up.

Comment: What's the output with the conditional? Is it sth like "10/2"? If so, try `document.write( parseInt(inboundAmount/2) );` or `document.write( parseInt(inboundAmount)/2);`

Comment: `$inbound_status first$` is this a php variable?

Comment: @osakagreg, please edit in your answers to tell us the outputs (or lack thereof) of the various codes in the browser. Thanks.

Comment: @Samleo Done.  I will answer comments at the bottom of the question itself from here forward.

Comment: Going vanilla, does `if ( document.querySelectorAll("#mycontent a.half").length > 0) {document.write(inboundAmount/2);} ` work? (Assuming that the DOM has <a class="half"></a> inside a table of id "mycontent")

Comment: Furthermore, must you use javascript/jquery for this? Assuming `$inbound_status` is the string "half", can you replace the `<script></script>` with a PHP code seeing if ` $inbound_status == 'half'` and echoing `$inboundAmount/2`

Answer (score 1):

The `this` scope inside your `<script>` tag will not point to the element you expect. Instead of checking in javascript you can check the condition in `php` itself. Otherwise, you can refer the code below to do it on javascript. You can use the php variable to check whether it contains the string `half`

```
echo "<td class='grav-results-td'>";
if (!empty($check_inbound)):
    echo "<a href=\"#inbound\" 
          class=\"$inbound_status first$id\" 
          onclick=\"comtype($id,'inbound',$vendor)\">
          $<script>if ('$inbound_status' == 'half' ) 
                    {document.write(inboundAmount/2);}
          </script>
          </a>"; 
endif; 
echo "</td>";
```

If `inboundAmount` is a php variable you can do it easily without using javascript

```
echo "<td class='grav-results-td'>";
if (!empty($check_inbound)):
    echo "<a href=\"#inbound\" 
          class=\"$inbound_status first$id\" 
          onclick=\"comtype($id,'inbound',$vendor)\">$";
    if ($inbound_status == 'half'): 
        echo $inboundAmount/2;
    endif;
    echo "</a>"; 
endif; 
echo "</td>"
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a page refresh, which is why I'm using javascript.  inboundAmount can certainly work as a php variable, but there is a lot of clicking going and the classes will change often.  So I need to be able to make it work with javascript.